# Windows 10: svn+ssh using TortoiseSVN and ssh

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn

I am trying to configure access to a subversion repository using TortoiseSVN on Windows 10.
I have installed my public key on the repository, and edited my config file for Subversion so that I have in the [tunnels] section.

```
ssh = ssh -q --
```

When I use TortoiseSVN repository browser, everything is fine.  I see the repository in the window.

However the problem is that approximately a dozen console windows appear and disappear while the connection is being made and the data is fetched.  This happens every time I navigate to a new location in the repository.

I get the data.  There is no interaction required.  Everything is working just as expected but for these windows appearing.  How can they be suppressed?

NOTE: I am configuring this to use the new Windows 10 ssh executable, because I want a solution that is as "out of the box" as possible. I (think that I) know how to achieve this using PuTTY, but I prefer not to.

Thanks in advance.  Stay well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

[tunnels]
ssh=TortoisePlink.exe -i C:/path/to/keyfile.ppk

(in settings, button to file is in General tab).

That will stop the incessant window creation.
Also, if you are running pageant, you can use -agent with that, and it will route through pageant even from cmd!